# I am trying to make this loop work, but I can't

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program to show me the biggest number from input integers from the user and I just really don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i  = 0;
        int rep = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int hi = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int big = 0;
        for( i = 0; i < rep; i++)
        {
            if(hi > big)
            {
                big = hi;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(big);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the loop looks alright but you only have 2 numbers, rep and hi.  repeatedly testing the same numbers doesnt make any difference.. So you dont need a loop

Comment: What is your goal? How many integers should a user enter? Is `rep` the expected number of integers?

Comment: ... or you keep the loop, read `hi` within it and add a condition to leave it and display the result

Comment: if `rep` is the expected number of integers, put `int hi = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` in your for loop before if clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect user to enter `rep` number of integers and then find the largest one, then this might work for you:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int rep = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int big = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < rep; i++)
        {
            int hi = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(hi > big)
            {
                big = hi;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(big);
    }
}
```

Assuming your inputs are natural numbers. Otherwise, you might want to replace

```cs
int big = 0;
```

with

```cs
int big = int.MinValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified as your `console.writeline` was out of loop. BUT

```
public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    int i  = 0;
    int rep = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int hi = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int big = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < rep; i++)
    {
        if(hi > big)
        {
            big = hi;
            Console.WriteLine(big);
        }

    }

}
}
```

BUT This code is assigning value of `hi` to `big` in first loop. Then enters in the 2nd loop and now it wont satisfy `if(hi > big)` condition as hi and big are now equal. And it will simply end of loop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,but the Console.WriteLine was, where it should have, because "big" was the number that i wanted displayed after al the proces was done.

Comment: Also, isn't the first loop in my code the for loop one? or i missunderstood your comment?